# Choose randomly from a list in Google Spreadsheets

Tags: google-sheets

Oftentimes you may have a "giveaway" of sorts. You have 20 people that put in their names into a drawing, and you want to choose say 3 of them at random.

Is there an easy way to do this via Google Sheets?

I know I can create a `=RANDBETWEEN(1,20)` several times, but that has two problems: every time I make a change the formula is recalculated, choosing a new number; additionally, if I have more than 10 winners, it's very likely that several of those `RANDBETWEEN`s will conflict with each other. E.g. saying that it should be awarded to the same person multiple times.

Once a name is chosen, it should be removed from the list so that the random function can't choose it again.

I see there's a [very complex formula](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/5251-google-sheets-select-random-from-list.html) I could use, but that will probably run into the same problems that it'll change each time the sheet is modified. I see there's also an [extension](https://www.ablebits.com/docs/google-sheets-shuffle-cells/) I could install, but I'd rather avoid 3rd party extensions.

Comment: freaking downvoters man I swear to god...

Answer (score 2):

Copy the range to another location. Highlight the range, right-click it, and choose **Randomize range**. You now have a new sorting for the range.

You could easily use this new sorting to choose the top N winners. E.g. the first 3 names in the list are your randomly chosen winners.